# Wordpress within a subdirectory of another Wordpress environment doesn't work

Tags: redirect, directory, installation, rel-canonical

Here's a summary of my scenario:

- I'm running Wordpress on a linux environment
- The root directory contains and `index.php` file that references the subdirectory where my main site's files are ([codex link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory)). Let's say this site is example.com
- Example.com works fine and pulls up the content that I have stored in my subfolder `/foo`
- I have another Wordpress site that I've set up, and I'd like it to be accessible at `example.com/bar`
- Visiting `example.com/bar` redirects me to the canonical URL e.g. `example.com/barhopping-is-fun`

No matter what I do, I can't seem to get `example.com/bar` to load my other Wordpress site.

Here's what I've done so far.

- Checked to make sure there is no `wp_terms` slug for `bar`
- Removed any non-standard `.htaccess` content from both the `/foo` and root directories.
- Modified the `.htaccess` in `/bar` to contain this (which results in an *internal server error*)

  - `RewriteBase /bar/`
  - `RewriteRule . /bar/index.php [L]`

[Followed this guide](http://liquidbook.com/2014/08/installing-second-wordpress-instance-subfolder/), which resulted in the error.
Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Edit: noticed that this Wordpress environment doesn't ever go to a 404 page. If it's a URL that is similar to a slug that exists it redirects to that slug. If it's a totally unknown URL it redirects to home. However there are no rules for this in `.htaccess` nor are there any redirect plugins running.

Comment: If you're setting the `RewriteBase` to `/bar/` then your first `RewriteRule` should just be `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ – [L]`... That's probably why you're getting a server error

Comment: Thanks that resolved the error however the `/bar` is still  redirecting to `example.com/barhopping-is-fun`, the wordpress in the subdirectory is just not getting picked up.

Comment: You need to exclude `/bar` from the rewrite rules in the `.htaccess` for your top-level WordPress site.